# CSS Move Icon to Right of Input Field

Tags: html, css

How do I move the magnifying glass to the right hand side in my input field?

Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhjLyf1k/).

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
body {
  margin: 30px;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #ebebeb inset;
}

.search input {
  text-indent: 32px;
}

.search .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
  <input placeholder="Search term">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set `left: 10px` to an icon too. Set there more pixels from left side, or directly pixels from right.

```
.search .fa-search {left: 230px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xhjLyf1k/1/

Setting right position instead of the left one (to prevent resizing of input field):

```
.search {display: inline-block} /* prevent 100% width */
.search .fa-search {left: auto; right: 10px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xhjLyf1k/2/

Answer (score 2):

you can also use a ::before pseudo-element within in the css itself to add a icon at right

```
.search::before {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  top: 50%;

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  right: 0rem;
  content: "";
  background-image: url('../images/search.png');
  background-size: contain;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='form-group'>
<label>Clave</label>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm" >
 <input class='form-control' type="password">
 <div class="input-group-btn">
 <button type="submit" id="togglePassword" class="btn btn-default fa fa-eye"></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap y Font Awesome
https://jsfiddle.net/jlujan/kgxo81fm/15/

Comment: You will need to edit your answer, explain why you think it works and include all code that you may have besides the one you have copied, since links will decay over time.

Answer (score 1):

Create a relative container span around the icon and input so the icon is always positioned relative to the input, rather than the div which is 100% width. Then you can move this component anywhere and have the icon work.

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
body {
  margin: 30px;
}

.search {

  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-element {
  position: relative;
}

.search input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #ebebeb inset;
}

.search input {
  text-indent: 1em;
}

.search .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
<span class="form-element">
  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
  <input placeholder="Search term">
  </span>
</div>
```